# Android inbuilt Video Calling

Tags: android, videochat

Yes i know this question has been asked several times but there is no convincing answer.

I dont want to make any complicated thing just i want to know if there is any way to call inbuilt android video calling functionality may be the same way we do voice call by intent.

Or are there any good api's for it.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startVideoCall(String number){

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall",Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
    intent.putExtra("videocall", true);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I am getting android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.phone.videocall dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx (has extras) }. can you please help me. Thank you in Advance